# Android - Possible to add broadcast to separate application?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

This might be a stretch, but I was wondering if it is possible to add functionality to an application that is already created for the android device.  Specifically, I would like to send a broadcast whenever the user tries to make a new search in the internet browser.  There might be another way to act only when the user searches the browser, but I thought this would be the easiest.  If this isn't possible (or is completely the wrong way of going about this), please let me know.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably query the `Browser` provider and get search data from it. Here is some basic code on how to do it:

```
Cursor cursor = this.context.getContentResolver().query(Browser.SEARCHES_URI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            final int indexDate = cursor.getColumnIndex(Browser.SearchColumns.DATE);
            final int indexTerm = cursor.getColumnIndex(Browser.SearchColumns.SEARCH);
            String date = cursor.getString(indexDate);
            String term = cursor.getString(indexTerm);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
```

Keep in mind that it would be better if you run queries on a separate `Thread` using the `Loader` framework.

I do not think there is a broadcast sent when a new search is performed.